# Json serializer - how to create a stream

Tags: c#, json, uwp

```
    public static async Task Store(ObservableCollection<Product> list)
    {
        Uri path = new Uri("ms-appx:///ListCollection.json");
        var store = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(path);
        var stream = File.OpenWrite(store.Path);
        var serialize = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<Product>));
        serialize.WriteObject(stream, list);
    }
```

Ok this is the piece of code that I used to serialize a collection , works very well , no problem with it , but what I want and tried and no success. I created a JSON file in my project. I want to store and stream data to that file. I tried some methods but no success , how do I open a stream to a file that is currently in my project?

EDITED : Commented the code that was working and wrote what I intend to do. Thanks for support.

When I get to this line

var stream = File.OpenWrite(store.Path); it says that is inaccesible.

What I intend to do is serialize some data to a file called ListCollection.json that is emtpy , that file is project file. It might be the stream or it might be the file that gives me that error. No idea.

Comment: What's up with the Downvote?

Comment: okay so you showed what worked. Could you show what didn't worked and maybe the error message that you received

Comment: Yes sir , you are right , edited.

Comment: What do you exactly need? Open a file that already exists and write more data to this file ?

Comment: What does the ListCollection.json contain ? What kind of project is this ? Console/Windows Forms/WPF.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your project file is located in the installation directory of your application and as far as I know you can't just write to that directory.

You would have to put a deployment action in your solution that writes the desired project file to the application data directory. There you should be able to write it.

Answer (score 0):

I looked through some of the documentation and came accross this:
[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx)

> The app's install directory is a read-only location.

I found a [Link](http://www.developerteacher.com/msdn/is-windows-applicationmodel-package-current-installedlocation-readonly-639521) which makes use of a little hack or so it seems.
I am not sure if this will work if the application is deployed etc.
but you can try this to write the file.
I am not sure if you need a stream or not but feel free to comment:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ObservableCollection<string> list = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        list.Add("Hallo");
        list.Add("Welt");
        Task t = Store(list);
    }

    public static async Task Store(ObservableCollection<string> list)
    {
        StorageFile file = await GetStorageFileFromApplicationUriAsync();
        if (file == null)
        {
            file = await GetStorageFileFromFileAsync();
        }

        if (file != null)
        {
            await file.DeleteAsync();
            await CreateFileInInstallationLocation(list);
        }      
    }

    private static async Task<StorageFile> GetStorageFileFromFileAsync()
    {
        StorageFile file = null;
        if (file == null)
        {
            try
            {
                StorageFolder folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
                file = await folder.GetFileAsync("ListCollection.json");
            }
            catch
            { }
        }
        return file;
    }

    private static async Task<StorageFile> GetStorageFileFromApplicationUriAsync()
    {
        StorageFile file = null;
        try
        {
            Uri path = new Uri("ms-appx:///ListCollection.json");
            file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(path);
        }
        catch
        { }
        return file;
    }

    private static async Task CreateFileInInstallationLocation(ObservableCollection<string> list)
    {
        var pkg = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current;
        var installedLocationFolder = pkg.InstalledLocation;

        try
        {
            var file = await installedLocationFolder.CreateFileAsync("ListCollection.json", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
            var filePath = file.Path;

            DataContractJsonSerializer serialize = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<String>));
            using (Stream stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
            {
                serialize.WriteObject(stream, list);
                stream.Flush();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var msg = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

What this basically does is:

1. Find the file
2. Delete the file
3. Create a new file
4. Write your JSON to the file

I am really not an expert on this matter and it even to me seems pretty hacky but it apparently does the job.
If you can avoid writing to the install directory do it and use the method Frank J proposed

Comment: Interesting! Thank you sir! I will give it a try , thank you for your time!

Comment: @MihailGeorgescu did you already have time to test the solution ? I am interested if the solution is working when it is deployed :)

Comment: If the content of the file is irrelevant (you delete it first and then recreate it) why do you need to deploy it in the first place then? That doesn't make a whole lot of sense. The installation directory is Read only exactly for the reason that you are not supposed to write runtime random info in there. That's what the apps data directory is for. Just write to a file in the data directory. If all you want is to fix the file name in the application at compile time put the file name into the config or the resources instead...

Comment: @FrankJ As you can see he wants to write it at position "ms-appx:///ListCollection.json" I don't ask why I give a solution but I also give the advice: do as Frank says ;). Maybe there is a good reason why he wants it that way, as stated above i am not an expert on this matter. Still I am stunned that microsoft allows to write into a read only directory